# smooth-div-scroll stops on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, smoothing, smooth-scrolling

Looking for a simple scroll right, nothing special.  My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // None of the options are set
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            mousewheelScrolling: false,
            hotSpotScrolling: false,
            autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Scrolling stops when you mouseover the right edge of the div.  Happens in Chrome and IE, otherwise seems to work fine???

Comment: which plugin are you using here? could you pass me the url for the plugin?

Comment: Using the plugin and all the same scripts, etc. from the current GitHub download

Comment: Figured out that if I make autoScrollingMode: "always" it works as you would expect.

Comment: The option "onstart" is for when you want autoscrolling directly after the page loads. As soon as the user interacts with the scroller in some way, autoscrolling will stop and not start again until you reload the page or tell it to start using a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // None of the options are set
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            autoScrollDirection: "endlessloopright",
            autoScrollingMode: "always"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this works like you intended!